# How to implement an equivalent of a Raw generic in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following generic interface:

```kotlin
interface Transformer<T, R> {
    fun transform(it: T): R
}
```

And I have the following class for transforming `null` inputs with a default value and delegating all non-null values to a non-null `Transformer`:

```kotlin
data class DefaultNullableTransformer<T, R>(
    val transformer: Transformer<T, R>,
    val default: R
) : Transformer<T?, R> {
    override fun transform(it: T?): R {
        val data = it ?: return default
        return transformer.transform(data)
    }
}
```

I have a serialization "framework" that I am using to serialize and deserialize classes.. Here are some relevant classes from it:

```kotlin
interface Serializer<T, D> {
    fun serialize(it: T, registry: SerializerRegistry): D
    fun deserialize(it: D, registry: SerializerRegistry): T
}

data class TypedData<T : Any>(val type: KClass<out T>, val data: Any)

class SerializerRegistry(private val defaultSerializer: Serializer<*, *>? = null) {
    private val serializers = mutableMapOf<KClass<*>, Serializer<*, *>>()

    fun <T : Any> register(type: KClass<T>, serializer: Serializer<T, *>) {
        serializers[type] = serializer
    }

    fun <T : Any> serialize(it: T) = TypedData(
        it::class,
        get(it::class).serialize(it, this)
    )

    fun <T : Any> deserialize(it: TypedData<T>): T = get(it.type).deserialize(it.data, this) as T

    private fun get(type: KClass<out Any>): Serializer<Any?, Any> {
        val serializer: Serializer<Any?, Any>? = serializers[type] as? Serializer<Any?, Any> ?: (defaultSerializer as Serializer<Any?, Any>?)
        return serializer ?: throw UnsupportedOperationException("Serializer for $type is not registered")
    }
}
```

I am having issues on how to implement a type-erased `Serializer` implementation. Here is how I can do it with Java using raw generics for `Transformer` and `DefaultNullableTransformer`:

```java
public class DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer implements Serializer<DefaultNullableTransformer, DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer.SerializedData> {
    @Override
    public SerializedData serialize(DefaultNullableTransformer transformer, SerializerRegistry registry) {
        TypedData<Transformer> transformerData = registry.serialize(transformer.getTransformer());
        Optional<TypedData<?>> defaultData = Optional.ofNullable(transformer.getDefault()).map(registry::serialize);
        return new SerializedData(transformerData, defaultData.orElse(null));
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultNullableTransformer deserialize(SerializedData data, SerializerRegistry registry) {
        Transformer transformer = registry.deserialize(data.getTransformer());
        Object defaultObj = data.getDefault() != null ? registry.deserialize(data.getDefault()) : null;
        return new DefaultNullableTransformer<>(transformer, defaultObj);
    }

    public static class SerializedData {
        private final TypedData<Transformer> transformer;
        private final TypedData<?> defaultData;

        public SerializedData(TypedData<Transformer> transformer, TypedData<?> defaultData) {
            this.transformer = transformer;
            this.defaultData = defaultData;
        }

        public TypedData<Transformer> getTransformer() {
            return transformer;
        }

        public TypedData<?> getDefault() {
            return defaultData;
        }
    }
}
```

With that class, I can simply register this serializer using:

```kotlin
register(DefaultNullableTransformer::class, DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer())
```

How can I convert this Java class into Kotlin without changing the `SerializerRegistry.register` signature? I have been trying for a long time using `Any?` and `*` but I cannot figure this out. I know that Kotlin has a stricter typing system than Java, so is this even possible? I am considering using a mix of Kotlin and Java just to get around this issue and that does not feel like the correct solution to me.

-- EDIT --

Here is a non-raw implementation of `DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer` as suggested in comments:

```java
public class DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer<T, R> implements Serializer<DefaultNullableTransformer<T, R>, DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer.SerializedData<T, R>> {

    @Override
    public SerializedData<T, R> serialize(DefaultNullableTransformer<T, R> transformer, SerializerRegistry registry) {
        TypedData<Transformer<T, R>> transformerData = registry.serialize(transformer.getTransformer());
        Optional<TypedData<?>> defaultData = Optional.ofNullable(transformer.getDefault()).map(registry::serialize);
        return new SerializedData<>(transformerData, defaultData.orElse(null));
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultNullableTransformer<T, R> deserialize(SerializedData<T, R> data, SerializerRegistry registry) {
        Transformer<T, R> transformer = registry.deserialize(data.getTransformer());
        Object defaultObj = data.getDefault() != null ? registry.deserialize(data.getDefault()) : null;
        return new DefaultNullableTransformer<>(transformer, (R) defaultObj);
    }

    public static class SerializedData<T, R> {
        private final TypedData<Transformer<T, R>> transformer;
        private final TypedData<?> defaultData;

        public SerializedData(TypedData<Transformer<T, R>> transformer, TypedData<?> defaultData) {
            this.transformer = transformer;
            this.defaultData = defaultData;
        }

        public TypedData<Transformer<T, R>> getTransformer() {
            return transformer;
        }

        public TypedData<?> getDefault() {
            return defaultData;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot register this serializer using: `register(DefaultNullableTransformer::class, DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer())` due to type mismatch, the code won't compile.

Comment: Using raw generics in Java is considered bad practice, so I would start by seeing how you can replace raw generics in Java with a wildcard, like `Transformer<?>`, and then do something similar in Kotlin using `*` - I know you said you've tried using `*` but I think that should solve it if you persevere.

Comment: Everything you said is correct and what I initially tried. I added a new section with your suggestion and where I got stuck when using non-raw implementation. That is actually how I ended up removing the generics and finally got it to work as I wanted to.

Comment: @k314159 I finally managed to do that and since your suggestion was correct, I will award you the bounty if you post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad you've worked it out with my help, but you should keep the bounty yourself as you did most of the hard work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by myself after all. My mistake was that I was always defining my `DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer` as a generic type in Kotlin... Here is how I finally did it:

```kotlin
class DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer : Serializer<DefaultNullableTransformer<*, *>, DefaultNullableTransformerSerializer.SerializedData> {

    override fun serialize(transformer: DefaultNullableTransformer<*, *>, registry: SerializerRegistry): SerializedData {
        val transformerData = registry.serialize(transformer.transformer)
        val defaultData = transformer.default?.let { registry.serialize(it) }
        return SerializedData(transformerData, defaultData)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun deserialize(data: SerializedData, registry: SerializerRegistry): DefaultNullableTransformer<*, *> {
        val transformer = registry.deserialize(data.transformerData) as Transformer<Any?, Any?>
        val defaultObj = data.defaultData?.let { registry.deserialize(it) as Any? }
        return DefaultNullableTransformer(transformer, defaultObj)
    }

    data class SerializedData(
        val transformerData: TypedData<*>,
        val defaultData: TypedData<*>?
    )
}
```